# DB to use for Phonegap and JQMobile

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

I am working on QA based app which I am developing with Phonegap and JQuery Mobile.
I am trying to create a template page which will pull random questions from DB and there multiple choice answers in random order too.

However, I am confused with the DB use to implement this functionality.
I thought about using SQLite, but that means writing and keeping lots of lines of code in my code base which would get initialized and executed when app loads. And I want to avoid this scenario.

Furthermore, I looked into IndexedDB, but it looks more on the same lines where I would be executing lines of code to create DB and records in it.

This is my first time creating an app. I come from programming background where we always have a DB ready for application and doesn't need to be initialized every time except for the connection. I was thinking of solution on similar line...

Any ideas on this...

Answer (score 2):

You may be best off just storing your arrays of questions and response options in [localStorage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage#localStorage). It's incredibly easy - and your data persists over app restarts and does not violate Apple's TOS regarding data storage/backup.

Comment: Check-out Lawnchair, it helps homogenize the different persistant-storage APIs. http://brian.io/lawnchair/. A note of warning, do as few reads/writes as possible because they cause work to be done on the disk space of the device, which is generally very slow.

Comment: Thanks @Robbo and Jasper...I will read about both of them and implement according to my needs.

Comment: @Robbo I looked into localStorage and went through all the stuff from DiveintoHTML5. It works in terms of key-value pairs and I'm not sure if this will be right solution for my query, as in each question will have 4 choices and 1 right answer.